# Particle system on sapling addon tree forces the leaves to be impaled

Tags: mesh, particles

I am currently watching a tutorial on YouTube "How to Create Low Poly Nature - Blender Tutorial" (at about 23/25 minutes).

The sapling addon is doing great, so is the weight paint view, but when I add a new particle set, go to hair, set emissions to 20, and do everything else that the "CGGeek" does, my leaves are impaled, using the center of my .png texture instead of the tip. 
I must have repeated the steps in this video half a dozen times for this one section.

Here are some pictures of my screen:
[image: Leaves weight paint]

[image: Tree Leaves]

Comment: Your problem is the leaf's object center. Objects are placed in the scene/particle system according to their center. See my answer here on how to fix it http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57812/using-unity-tree-editor-with-blender-trees/57817#57817

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed everything. Now my sapling is looking as beautiful as the day it was planted. Or something. It looks good.